# Which Ubuntu is best for me >>?

Tags: system-installation

My laptop specs are:
intel 5th gen i3
8gb ram
intel hd5500
.
.
I am using windows 10 original version , and I don't want to remove it. but i also want ubuntu running in my laptop.
please guide me.

Comment: More an opinion than anything else

Comment: It really doesn't matter which version you use. I'm running Ubuntu Budgie on a Parrot Chromebook with 2 GB of RAM and, even though it freezes sometimes, it still runs fine. If you're new to Ubuntu, I always recommend going with straight, normal Ubuntu. Once you've gotten kind of used to it, you can branch out into other flavours from there.

Comment: Yes I am new to ubuntu and I never used linux. So please tell me which one is simple ubuntu and which version ? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @AbhishekMalik If you're not sure, just use regular Ubuntu. With those specs, you can run any flavour anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think Ubuntu 16.04 LTS would be best for you since you are a newbie in Linux. I personally use that version, too. Download the Ubuntu image here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.

LTS stands for [Long Term Support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS). Every 6 months a new version of Ubuntu is released, and every 2 years an LTS version comes which has generally 5 years of support. The latest version of Ubuntu is 17.04, but since you are a beginner I strongly suggest to use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

If you don't want to remove Windows OS, then you need to install Ubuntu as a dual boot. You can google that and see some videos on youtube and read some blogs which will guide you on what you need to do. For example, see [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/301745)

Welcome to the Linux family.

Comment: @AbhishekMalik You are welcome.